# Rails in production not rendering application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know it's hard/impossible to troubleshoot without our code but I'm hoping someone might give us a clue as to **where to BEGIN looking** to troubleshoot this problem? `production.log` looks normal and application is functional..just NO stylesheets or header/footer because application.html.erb layout isn't being called...which is apparent when we view source: no `<html> <head> <body>` etc...

Works fine in Development!?!

Passenger 3,
Apache 2,
Rails 3.0.7,
Ruby 1.9.2p180
RVM 1.6.5

**Update**: adding environment info per request

`production.rb` & `development.rb` are stock from initial `rails new appname -T -J`. This app is bare-bones (one resource) just trying to get round-trip functional on a new client's server.

**Update2** strangely when I `touch approot/tmp/restart.txt` to restart Passenger per their docs: "Passenger will restart on next request" the file `restart.txt` remains. So A) Passenger is not seeing it and restarting...or B) Passenger doesn't delete it automatically which seems abnormal.

So, wondering now if my application may be running on the System's Ruby/Rails (2.3.5?) and not the RVM version. How to verify?

Comment: IMHO, it's actually good that you don't post any code.  This way, this question could be a collection of what can cause discrepancy  between production and development rendering.

Comment: Have you made sure it's not a caching issue, maybe it's caching a very old version of your page?

Comment: (1) What are the differences between your production.rb and development.rb, environment setups? (2) What are the webserver (settings & software version) differences between dev & production (are you running the same version of Apache and Rails on the dev machines)?

Comment: well, i don't think so...as this is a first run situation. tried restarting apache `apachectl -k graceful` and `touch approot/tmp/restart.txt` to no avail.

Comment: are you using HAML? or does your gemfile have haml installed?

Comment: So, wondering now if my application may be running on the System's Ruby/Rails (2.3.5?) and not the RVM version. How to verify? <- do a which ruby and you'll see which ruby your system is using

Comment: @corroded: Had `gem 'haml-rails'` in `:dev, :test` block and the application.html.haml was the ONLY view done in haml. rest were still erb. moved `gem 'haml-rails'` out of block and now all is working. Submit an answer and i'll toss you the 15 bones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the HAML gem that's causing you trouble. You probably have a blank .haml file(if you're still using erbs) or a blank erb file if you're using mostly HAML files.

Comment: Had `gem haml-rails` in wrong location in my Gemfile (see comment above).